# Foreground Service retains memory objects

Tags: android, memory-management

My Android application is essentially a foreground service. The User Interface aspect of the application is for settings and configuration of this foreground service.

When the service is started via the application UI, it begins showing memory usage of 23mb.

When Android starts the service (at boot for example) it begins showing memory usage of 7mb. If the application UI is opened, the memory usage increases to 23mb.

When onDestroy() is called in the MainActivity of the UI, the associated drawables and resources remain in the memory attached to the foreground service and do not get garbage collected.

I can 'resolve' the problem by calling `System.exit(0)` in onDestroy() of the MainActivity. Android then restarts the foreground service at 7mb.

Additionally, I can use the `android:process` tag in the Manifest to separate the UI and the service elements.

Neither of the above 'solutions' is addressing the actual issue though, which I hope to do with your help!

Using the MAT tool via Eclipse, I can see that various objects are retained in the memory, the only two of significant size being:

```
Class Name | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap Percentage

class android.content.res.Resources @ 0x40ef7910 System Class|           40 |     8,475,664 |     68.71%
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState @ 0x411beb20|       40 |     1,127,720 |     9.14%
```

Examining the path to gc roots gives no clues as to why these are remaining in the memory, or what is holding a reference to them.

I've experimented with the contexts I'm using `MainActivity.this` and `getApplicationContext()` and removed references to static variables, but I just cannot get rid of these memory objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Path to gc roots excluding weak references:**

```
Class Name | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap

class android.content.res.Resources @ 0x40ef7910 System Class|     40 |     8,475,664

Class Name      | Shallow Heap Retained Heap

android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable$BitmapState @ 0x411beb20|  40 | 1,127,720

Class Name                              | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap**

[224] java.lang.Object[510] @ 0x41843738|        2,056 |     8,466,904

mValues android.util.LongSparseArray @ 0x40f46b28|  24 |     8,471,024

sPreloadedDrawables class android.content.res.Resources @ 0x40ef7910 SystemClass|          40 |     8,475,664

Found 1 path. No more paths left - for both entries.
```

Comment: Can you post the path to GC roots of both object excluding weak references? Also, have you tried to force recycle the bitmap by calling `system.gc()`? Although that is not recommended, you could see if you problem is reference being held or GC has not get around to recycle it.

Comment: @wangyif2 - Thanks, I've edited the post. Sorry about the formatting. I've experimented with the garbage collection, but it's not cleared no matter how many times I call it. It remains in the memory hours later too.

Comment: Any solutions yet? I have exactly the same issue. In my case the foreground service takes ages to restart if I call system.exit(0) in on destroy of the activity. So, even that isn't an option for me.

Comment: @user1951805 Unfortunately not. I have to call System.exit(0) as described. I've not found a solution :(

Comment: Does your service restart immediately after calling System.exit(0)?

Comment: @user1951805 - Normally between 3-10 seconds. So it's not too bad.

Comment: It may take any arbitrary amount of time to restart the thread. I don't think we can be sure about it. Btw, I observed that after sometime, generally when doing heavy multitasking or running memory intensive apps, the ram usage of my app drops to the service only level(4-12mb) and stays there unless the UI is launched again. When this happens, I don't even see the service being restarted. This also happens after service runs for a long period of time. Is the process being recreated or it finally getting garbage collected? I suspect the former. So, ram is actually being reclaimed when needed.

Comment: @brandall Same issue here, any updates?

Comment: I'm afraid not @Pedram I still have to manually kill it and then allow Android to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

> My Android application is essentially a foreground service. The User Interface aspect of the application is for settings and configuration of this foreground service.

This is appropriate for a vanishingly small number of apps.

> Examining the path to gc roots gives no clues as to why these are remaining in the memory, or what is holding a reference to them.

The `Resources` one, at minimum, is in every Dalvik process and cannot be removed. Most likely the `BitmapDrawable$BitmapState` is tied to the `Resources`.

Comment: "This is appropriate for a vanishingly small number of apps" - My application is necessarily unique in this implementation. I've updated the post. Sorry about the formatting. Does it give you any clues?

Comment: @andjav: "My application is necessarily unique in this implementation" -- if you say so. "Does it give you any clues?" -- my answer still stands.

Comment: "The Resources one, at minimum, is in every Dalvik process and cannot be removed. Most likely the BitmapDrawable$BitmapState is tied to the Resources" - Would you be able to explain why calling System.exit(0) removes this memory usage though and my application continues with a memory usage hovering around 7mb? When you say "it can't be removed', aspects of it, clearly can....?

Comment: @andjav: You are assuming that your 7MB and 23MB values are accurate and measure the same thing that MAT is. It is also conceivable that these objects are shared between processes, as is the VM itself and class definitions, though I am not aware that to be the case.

Comment: It certainly does appear so from my analysis... Thanks for your input - looks like for now I'm stuck using System.exit(0) though :(