# Android Kills Background Services in Xiaomi, Huawei etc

Tags: android, background-service, huawei-mobile-services, xiaomi

I need to make my service unstoppable. I tried to return START_STICKY on start command, it works well on emulator but, when remove the app from task manager on my device (Xiaomi mi5s, Android 7), it doesn't create itself again.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Edit: I gave Auto Start permission and disabled battery protection rules for the app.

Edit: Also I tried to use foreground service. However, it is being killed too..

```
   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Hello!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher2)
                .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        startForeground(1, notification);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


---Activity
       ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, new Intent(this, LockerService.class));
```

Logcat

```
2018-10-31 21:24:22.143 2168-2168/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
2018-10-31 21:24:22.555 1513-3093/? D/ProcessManager: update DY:[com.touchtype.swiftkey, com.miui.voip]
2018-10-31 21:24:22.560 1513-3093/? D/ProcessManager: remove task: TaskRecord{36f7d55 #495 A=me.ibrahimsn.applock U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
2018-10-31 21:24:22.607 3103-3296/? I/WtEventController: dispatchSysInfoEvent AM_NEW_INTENT componentName:com.miui.home/.launcher.Launcher
2018-10-31 21:24:22.610 1513-9074/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
2018-10-31 21:24:22.624 1513-9074/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:44879245
2018-10-31 21:24:22.626 1513-1604/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityStopTrigger 
2018-10-31 21:24:22.628 1513-1620/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:44879248
2018-10-31 21:24:22.630 1513-12578/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:44879251
2018-10-31 21:24:22.633 3185-3185/? D/SearchCardView: onVisibilityChanged: 0
2018-10-31 21:24:22.635 3185-3831/? I/RenderThread: RenderThread resumed
2018-10-31 21:24:22.635 3185-3831/? D/ScreenElementRoot: resume
2018-10-31 21:24:22.639 3185-3831/? I/NotifierManager: onRegister: miui.maml.NotifierManager$MultiBroadcastNotifier@46712e7
2018-10-31 21:24:22.646 1513-3093/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:44879267
2018-10-31 21:24:22.680 1513-1620/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:44879301
2018-10-31 21:24:22.686 2134-2134/? V/PhoneStatusBarPolicy: updateManagedProfile mManagedProfileFocused: false mManagedProfileInQuietMode: false mKeyguardVisible: false mCurrentUserId:0 mCurrentProfileId:0 mSecondSpaceStatusIconVisible: true showIcon:false
2018-10-31 21:24:22.689 1513-10970/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 4
2018-10-31 21:24:22.694 2134-2134/? D/StatusBar: onNotificationRemoved:  Key: 0|me.ibrahimsn.applock|1|null|10637
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Removing apps from recents kills their process, including services. Unless there's broadcast/event to start them again, they won't be recreated.

Comment: But it works well on emulator and other devices. START_STICKY is for restarting service after destroy. @Pawel

Comment: Use a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).

Comment: It is stops too :( @greeble31

Comment: @mystogan In that case, you may want to ask a new question, or research some tutorials on foreground services. They are a well-documented way of addressing the problem you have described.

Comment: Foreground services is for min API 26, my device is API 24 @greeble31

Comment: @mystogan That's a common misconception. Use [`Service.startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)); available since API level 5.

Comment: I have edited my question @greeble31

Comment: @mystogan So, just to clarify: You start the app, you see your icon in the notification bar, everything's fine, and then when you close the app by tapping the "X" or by using a swipe gesture, the app terminates and the notification bar icon disappears. Correct? Is there any logcat output associated with app termination?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I have added logcat output that when I swipe and kill the application. @greeble31

Comment: @mystogan I'm not seeing anything recognizable in the logcat. Maybe this is a [problem with certain Xioami devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428242/foreground-service-gets-killed-on-performing-internet-related-operations)

Comment: Yes, its related to Xiaomi. Thanks for the answers @greeble31

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442078/background-services-are-restricted-in-xiaomi-and-oppo). I had same problem and, after lots of research, I figured it out:  You must white-list your app.

Answer (score 1):

There are some customizations on Chinese roms regarding app lifecycle.

Xiaomi kills foreground services indiscriminately (xiaomi redmi note4 (Android N), note 7 (Android P)). So it's really difficult to have the same behavihour on all phones.

You can try to relaunch your foreground service using an alarm with a broadcast receiver.
When you app is being killed you need to set this alarm. When the intent is received try to start the foreground service with startForeground(). Remember also to bind the foreground service and disable battery limitation (and others things related) according to your device.

I don't know if this works because we have no necessity to implement such a method. But you could give it a try.

Remember that for Android >= Oreo the only way for a service to survive and works seems to be the foreground service way.(Bound service with battery optimization off for some devices)

You can find useful material at:

[Never Ending background service](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android)

[LocationUpdatesForegroundService](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService)

The second example works on emulator on different version of android(5/7). It works on Galaxy S3 with Resurrection Remix rom (Android 7) and works on some Huawei models (Oreo, Pie).

Work with services in android is really difficult. Have patience and go on.