# Periodic Work Manager not working in Oreo when Swipe out the app from recent apps

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I was implementing the Work Manager.As per documentation, work manager will give the guarantee to execute your task. But When i am using in OREO and swiping out the application from recent apps then work manager is not working. It will be a great help if anyone can suggest me what i am doing the wrong.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder photoWorkBuilder =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SchedulePullApiWorker.class, 15,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    PeriodicWorkRequest myWork = photoWorkBuilder
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(myWork);
```

Here is my worker class

```
public class SchedulePullApiWorker extends Worker {


public SchedulePullApiWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    showNotification();
    return Result.success();
}
```

Gradle :

```
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-rc02"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-rxjava2:1.0.0-rc02"
```

Comment: Check Logcat to see if your code is crashing (e.g., trying to access some `static` value that is now `null` with a fresh process).

Comment: @CommonsWare Checked it i did not found any crash or error related to work manager.

Comment: @CommonsWare When i am Opening the application then work manager is working fine. but only if i swipe it out from recent apps the work manager is not working.

Comment: Maybe this ->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54457935/7976274   would help you.