# Why Android Oreo kills app's foreground service?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, kill-process, foreground-service

Last time, I found an application, which gets a location in the background on Android Oreo. I noticed, that system kills foreground service, when I open or click some options in Settings or Camera app. Instead, a notification from app, system shows own with title "App using battery". I test an app on tablet Huawei MediaPad T5 with Android 8.

I set Ignore optimizations and Manage manually in Battery options. I set also return value in onStartCommand to START_STICKY. I added WakeLock in onCreate service's method. I checked, that device had free RAM and despite this, Android killed my service. I tried also block "App using battery" notification, but the system killed foreground service and restarted it sometime later.

I used 
adb shell dumpsys activity services
and foreground service is in dle middle in LRU list. Despite this, Android 8 killed the service.

I use app from [GitHub repository](https://github.com/BlackBlind567/Location_Updates-Background_Foreground).

Full LocationUpdatesService class:

```
public class LocationUpdatesService extends Service {

private static final String PACKAGE_NAME =
        "com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationupdatesforegroundservice";

private static final String TAG = "resPOINT";

/**
 * The name of the channel for notifications.
 */
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";

static final String ACTION_BROADCAST = PACKAGE_NAME + ".broadcast";

static final String EXTRA_LOCATION = PACKAGE_NAME + ".location";
private static final String EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION = PACKAGE_NAME +
        ".started_from_notification";

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

/**
 * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
 */
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000;

/**
 * The fastest rate for active location updates. Updates will never be more frequent
 * than this value.
 */
private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
        UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

/**
 * The identifier for the notification displayed for the foreground service.
 */
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345678;

/**
 * Used to check whether the bound activity has really gone away and not unbound as part of an
 * orientation change. We create a foreground service notification only if the former takes
 * place.
 */
private boolean mChangingConfiguration = false;

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

/**
 * Contains parameters used by {@link com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi}.
 */
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

/**
 * Provides access to the Fused Location Provider API.
 */
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

/**
 * Callback for changes in location.
 */
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

private Handler mServiceHandler;

Double latitude, longitude;

/**
 * The current location.
 */
private Location mLocation;


/**
 * Realtime location save in firestore or firebase*/
GeoFire geoFire;
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
DocumentReference documentReference;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public LocationUpdatesService() {
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            onNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
        }
    };

    createLocationRequest();
    getLastLocation();

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG);
    handlerThread.start();
    mServiceHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "wl:location");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    // Android O requires a Notification Channel.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
        // Create the channel for the notification
        NotificationChannel mChannel =
                new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        // Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service started");
    boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION,
            false);

    // We got here because the user decided to remove location updates from the notification.
    if (startedFromNotification) {
        removeLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }
    // Tells the system to not try to recreate the service after it has been killed.
    return START_STICKY;
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mChangingConfiguration = true;
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) comes to the foreground
    // and binds with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground service
    // when that happens.
    Log.i(TAG, "in onBind()");
    stopForeground(true);
    mChangingConfiguration = false;

    // Register Firestore when service will restart
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    return mBinder;
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) returns to the foreground
    // and binds once again with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground
    // service when that happens.
    Log.i(TAG, "in onRebind()");
    stopForeground(true);
    mChangingConfiguration = false;

    // Register Firestore when service will restart
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    super.onRebind(intent);
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Last client unbound from service");

    // Called when the last client (MainActivity in case of this sample) unbinds from this
    // service. If this method is called due to a configuration change in MainActivity, we
    // do nothing. Otherwise, we make this service a foreground service.
    if (!mChangingConfiguration && Utils.requestingLocationUpdates(this)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting foreground service");
        /*
        // TODO(developer). If targeting O, use the following code.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mNotificationManager.startServiceInForeground(new Intent(this,
                    LocationUpdatesService.class), NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        } else {
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
         */

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());


    }
    return true; // Ensures onRebind() is called when a client re-binds.
}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mServiceHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}

/**
 * Makes a request for location updates. Note that in this sample we merely log the
 * {@link SecurityException}.
 */
public void requestLocationUpdates() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Requesting location updates");
    Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdatesService.class));
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
        Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
    }
}

/**
 * Removes location updates. Note that in this sample we merely log the
 * {@link SecurityException}.
 */
public void removeLocationUpdates() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Removing location updates");
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
        stopSelf();
    } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
        Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
        Log.d(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not remove updates. " + unlikely);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the {@link NotificationCompat} used as part of the foreground service.
 */
private Notification getNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class);

    CharSequence text = Utils.getLocationText(mLocation);

    // Extra to help us figure out if we arrived in onStartCommand via the notification or not.
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);

    // The PendingIntent that leads to a call to onStartCommand() in this service.
    PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // The PendingIntent to launch activity.
    PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launch, getString(R.string.launch_activity),
                    activityPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.remove_location_updates),
                    servicePendingIntent)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentTitle(Utils.getLocationTitle(this))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker(text)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
    }


    return builder.build();
}

private void getLastLocation() {
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                            mLocation = task.getResult();
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to get location.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Lost location permission." + unlikely);
    }
}

private void onNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "New location: " + location);

    mLocation = location;

    // Notify anyone listening for broadcasts about the new location.
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BROADCAST);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION, location);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

    // Update notification content if running as a foreground service.
    if (serviceIsRunningInForeground(this)) {
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());

        // Getting location when notification was call.
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Here using to call Save to serverMethod
        SavetoServer();

    }
}

/**
 * Sets the location request parameters.
 */
private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Since this service runs in the same process as its
 * clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocationUpdatesService getService() {
        return LocationUpdatesService.this;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if this is a foreground service.
 *
 * @param context The {@link Context}.
 */
public boolean serviceIsRunningInForeground(Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (getClass().getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            if (service.foreground) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


/**
 * Save a value in realtime to firestore when user in background
 * For foreground you have to call same method to activity
 * */

private void SavetoServer(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Save to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("resMM", "Send to server");
    Log.d("resML", String.valueOf(latitude));
    Log.d("resMLL", String.valueOf(longitude));

    Map<String , String> driverMap = new HashMap<>();

    driverMap.put("name" , String.valueOf(latitude));
    driverMap.put("email" , String.valueOf(longitude));

    documentReference = firebaseFirestore
            .collection("driverAvaliable")
            .document("newdriver");

    documentReference.update("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude),
                                "longitude", String.valueOf(longitude),
                                "timeStamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp())
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
        }
    });
}
```

I changed START_NOT_STICKY in onStartCommand to START_STICKY and I added WakeLock code to onCreate in LocationUpdatesService.

Service after killing restarts from few seconds to few minutes. The worst case is when the system kills service and user sets the screen to off. Then Android not restarts this service and app not gets locations in the background. User must set screen on and unlock the device.

I would like to system not kill my service. If is not possible, Android should restart it immediatelly. How to achieve it?

Comment: post your service class code here

Comment: Do you want to receive location updates from the background? See [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits).

Comment: I had similar problem , It's not app problem , the problem is with devices killing services , check https://dontkillmyapp.com/ for some instructions on how to keep service running .

Comment: Also check out my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399485/is-there-any-way-to-run-service-continuously-in-android .

Comment: @Quicklearner I added full service class with modifications to question.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Location updates work good. I have only problem with killing foreground service by system.

Comment: The only solution that I found is toasked user to turn off automatic aplication optymalization in battery settings. But solution dependent on user isn't good idea. Did you found any solution?

Comment: On app's settings, I can disable "App using battery" notification. The path is: app's settings -> Baterry -> settings icon in right top conner -> set "Remider hight use of battery" to off. EMUI kills the app significantlly less. If app is killed, system restarts it in some time. As programmer, you have little influence on app's running in system. You have to write own mobile system and upload it on device.