# Background Service gets killed on clearing from recents in MIUI

Tags: android

Jugnoo Driver App has not been whitelisted in the Auto Start but yet it again starts the service after some time !
How jugnoo rider app runs even it is not Auto start too

I have done notification stuff , changed the manifest to stopWithTask="false" .

Comment: see https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi

Comment: I have had little bit of success with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54457592/6478047

Comment: done all this earlier but wanted to know how jugnoo or zomoto rider app revokes its service even they have not implemented all this stuff

Answer (score -1):

I have created a service for same issue, 
please check it out with this. 
It will help you

```
public class GpsServices extends Service implements LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {
Data data;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private Data.onGpsServiceUpdate onGpsServiceUpdate;
private Looper mServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
public  String gps_notification = "gps_channel";

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
    // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
    // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
    // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);

    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    if (data == null) {
        data = new Data(onGpsServiceUpdate);
    } else {
        data.setOnGpsServiceUpdate(onGpsServiceUpdate);
    }

    gpsListener();

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (mLocationManager.getAllProviders().indexOf(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) >= 0) {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 0, this);
    } else {
        Log.w("SideMenuActivity", "No GPS location provider found. GPS data display will not be available.");
    }

    if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Gps not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("data", "");
    data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);

    if (data == null) {
        data = new Data(onGpsServiceUpdate);
    } else {
        data.setOnGpsServiceUpdate(onGpsServiceUpdate);
    }

    String speed = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.0f", location.getSpeed() * 3.6);

    Toast.makeText(this, speed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.e("isRunningFalse", speed);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
    // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;//needed for stop.

    if (intent != null) {
        msg.setData(intent.getExtras());
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(GpsServices.this, "The Intent to start is null?!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // We don't provide binding, so return null
    return null;
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Services is stopped */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    mLocationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(this);
    stopForeground(true);
}

@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
    switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") GpsStatus gpsStatus = mLocationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
            int satsInView = 0;
            int satsUsed = 0;
            Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats = gpsStatus.getSatellites();
            for (GpsSatellite sat : sats) {
                satsInView++;
                if (sat.usedInFix()) {
                    satsUsed++;
                }
            }

            if (satsUsed == 0) {
                data.setRunning(false);
                stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), GpsServices.class));
            //                    firstfix = true;
            }
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gps not enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

// Handler that receives messages from the thread
private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //promote to foreground and create persistent notification.
        //in Oreo we only have a few seconds to do this or the service is killed.
        Notification notification = getNotification("App is running");
        startForeground(msg.arg1, notification);  //not sure what the ID needs to be.
        // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
        // For our example, we just sleep for 5 seconds then display toasts.
        //setup how many messages
        int times = 1, i;

        Bundle extras = msg.getData();
        if (extras != null) {
            times = 1000*60*60*24;  //default is one
        }
        //loop that many times, sleeping for 5 seconds.
        for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait(5000); //5 second sleep
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            String info = i + "GPS SPEED LOG";
            Log.d("intentServer", info);
            //make a toast
            //unable to ensure the toasts will always show, so use a handler and post it for later.
            // Toast.makeText(MyForeGroundService.this, info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
        // the service in the middle of handling another job
        //            stopSelf(msg.arg1);  //notification will go away as well.
    }
}

// build a persistent notification and return it.
public Notification getNotification(String message) {

    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), gps_notification)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mylocation)
            .setOngoing(true)  //persistent notification!
            .setChannelId(gps_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Gps Service")   //Title message top row.
            .setContentText(message)  //message when looking at the notification, second row
            .build();  //finally build and return a Notification.
}
         }
```

Comment: Please add some content to you answer , instead of posting link only answer

Comment: are you sure that all that code is required just to prevent killing app?